# How do I set up variety to show me a up to date map of earth?

Tags: downloads, 23.10, variety

I just downloaded variety and I know NASA serves pics of Earth I just don't know how to make variety put up a map of Earth that gets updated.

Comment: Do you know the url for the image?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].